# Magento and Fancybox - Block CMS loading inline

Tags: ajax, magento, fancybox, inline

Situation:
We have several small icons on our Magento Product page. After clicking one, a fancybox opens with content from a CMS Block.

Problem:
It seems that fancybox isn't "compiling" the block content properly. The magento variables aren't converted into "readable" code.

Here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/24qyYinD

Output:

```
<div id="data-winddicht">
<div class`enter code here`="technologie_lightbox">
<div class="image"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Technology/Wasserdicht.png"}}" alt="" /></div>
<p>LOREM TEST</p>
</div>
```

{{media url=""}} wasn't converted into html code.

any hints?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/210263/#t399724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is here:
magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/210263/#t399724

Thanks to Kalpesh Mehta

Code:
From

```
echo $block->getContent();
```

to

```
echo $this->helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($block->getContent());
```